# Is there a way to combine Rmpi & mclapply?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mpi

I have some R code that applies a function to a list of objects. The function is simple but involves a bootstrapping calculation, which can be easily sped up using `mclapply`. When run on a single node, everything is fine.

However, I have a cluster and what I've been trying to do is to distribute the application of the function to the list of objects across multiple nodes. To do this I've been using `Rmpi` (0.6-6).

The code below runs fine

```
library(Rmpi)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(10, type='MPI')
parallel::clusterExport(cl, varlist=c('as.matrix'), envir=environment())
descriptor <- parallel::parLapply(1:5, function(am) {
    val <- mean(unlist(lapply(1:120, function(x) mean(rnorm(1e7)))))
    return(c(val, Rmpi::mpi.universe.size()))
}, cl=cl)
print(do.call(rbind, descriptor))
snow::stopCluster(cl)
```

However, if I convert the `lapply` to `mclapply` and set `mc.cores=10`, MPI warns that forking will lead to bad things, and the job hangs.

(In all cases jobs are being submitted via SLURM)

Based on the MPI warning, it seems that I should not be using `mclapply` within `Rpmi` jobs. Is this a correct assessment?

If so, does anybody have suggestions on how I can parallelize the function that is being run on each node?

Comment: Not directly addressing your question, but my understanding is that it is possible to use the snow functions (included in the parallel package) to construct a cluster and then use the multicore functions (also included in the parallel package, like `mcapply`) to run in parallel in each node. I have not tried this though.

Comment: Indeed - that's what I've been doing. The code above uses methods from the base `parallel` package, rather than making `Rmpi` calls directly. (However, the job is started on the cluster using `mpiexec`).